# Addressing using MAC address

Tags: networking

Why broadcast is happening in RARP request, we already know the sender and destination MAC address. Just send unicast request and get the IP address. What is the reason for using broadcasting?

Comment: For what RARP used to be used for, the computer would not know to which MAC address to send a packet. Not an eletrical engineering question.

Comment: Rama Siva Subrahmanyam - Welcome :) (a) Generic networking questions are off-topic here (notwithstanding that you got an answer). Please see the [on-topic](/help/on-topic) subjects on this site. This site does not try to answer general computing Q&A. I recommend you also read the [tour] & the rest of the [help] to become more familiar with the site rules. (b) Do not [duplicate questions across different Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). You asked the [same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358454) 2 hours ago. Please delete it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original reason is for a computer to **discover its own IP address**, and at the point of booting, the computer would *not know* the MAC address of any servers to help.

> Network hosts such as diskless workstations frequently do not know
> their protocol addresses when booted; they often know only their
> hardware interface addresses.  To communicate using higher-level
> protocols like IP, they must discover their protocol address from
> some external source.  Our problem is that there is no standard
> mechanism for doing so. -- From [RFC 903](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc903).

It would send RARP asking for the IP address of its own MAC address, and some kindly server would answer.  (Or sometimes a mischievous pretend server, in many university labs.)

Other methods used at the time included each computer having a file `/etc/ethers` or using a vendor specific protocol such as Sun's YP.

Nowadays most computers use BOOTP or DHCP, which assign the IP address, perhaps from the server's database of MAC address to IP address mappings.

Comment: The original reason is for a computer to discover its own IP address, and at the point of booting, the computer would not know the MAC address of any servers to help.

thank you for this point ..

Comment: The whole idea is how to avoid individual configuration of the workstations, so have to discover everything during boot.. This is even more important today than ever because of the number of communicating microcontrollers, and is a very general problem, not restricted to IP and ethernet.